# Integrating Ruby on Windows WAMP server so I can run Ruby and PHP at same time?

Tags: ruby, wamp, wampserver

I've been searching on this but haven't found anything decisive so far.. I already have a windows WAMP server up and running and am using it for my PHP apps, I want to be able to run some small ruby scripts (to interact with a library that is not available in PHP), I don't even need Rails at this point, I just want to run ruby scripts and be able to run them from within a web browser type environment (like PHP) but I can't figure out how to do this since the "instant rails" takes the same resources of php and apache so it can't run at the same time unless I change the port but I'd rather just make it so it runs off the same apache as my PHP apps ( I don't even need a database at this point as thats all handled in my php apps).. any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you have accepted the answer from your other question: you won't be able to run a ruby TCP server on port X and Apache on the same port.

On the other hand if you decide to use Rails: Install InstantRails but don't start it. Copy the portion of Apache config (in InstantRails directory) that binds rails to Apache and edit it to handle everything under (for eample) /rails then paste it into your Apache config that runs PHP. You may have to fiddle with paths (PATH variable). This way you'll have Apache running on port X, all *.php will go to your PHP interpreter and everything under (for example) /rails will go to Rails/Ruby